# Merging and manipulating JSON arrays in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my model i'm getting two Json arrays from both the facebook's and twitter's api.

```
facebook_friends = { "data": 
  [{"name": "Friend Joe", "id": "123"}, 
   {"name": "Friend Jane", "id": "12342"}]}
twitter_friends = { "users": 
  [{"name": "Other friend joe", "id": "333"}, 
   {"name": "Other friend Jane", "id": "456"}]}
```

And I want to build an array like this (NB: i'm appending the provider key to identify the source of the data)

```
all_friends = [
  {"name": "Friend Joe", "id": "123", "provider": "facebook"},
  {"name": "Friend Jane", "id": "12342", "provider": "facebook"}, 
  {"name": "Other friend joe", "id": "333", "provider": "twitter"},
  {"name": "Other friend Jane", "id": "456", "provider": "twitter"}]
```

I can do this with jquery like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/gm3jJ/  but how do i do it in ruby? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using those lines:

```
facebook_array = JSON.parse('{ "data": [{"name": "Friend Joe", "id": "123"}, {"name": "Friend Jane", "id": "12342"}]}')["data"].map{|h| h.merge({'provider' => 'facebook'})}
twitter_array = (JSON.parse('[{"name": "Other friend joe", "id": "333"}, {"name": "Other friend Jane", "id": "456"}]').map{|h| h.merge({'provider' => 'twitter'})})
final_array = facebook_array.concat(twitter_array)
```

**Edit**: Don't forget to require json, like this before executing the above code: `require 'json'`

Comment: Thanks, is final_array a json array?

Comment: no, it isn't a json array, it is a ruby array.
You can get a json array back by doing `final_array.to_json`, and it will be yours :)

Comment: All the pleasure is mine
Don't forget to click on "accepted answer" on the left of my answer please :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine stuff, you can just do it like this:

```
# Get the array of friends from each service and add provider
fb = JSON.parse(facebook_friends)["data"].map {|x| x["provider"] = "facebook"}
tw = JSON.parse(twitter_friends)["users"].map {|x| x["provider"] = "twitter"}
# Concatenate them into one array
fb + tw
```